# Key translation error in using shiny.i18n in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, internationalization, translation

I want to start with translation in R Shiny. At the very beginning, I am creating the simplest app in Shiny and trying to translate it. But I get the following error:

```
Warning in load_local_config(translation_csv_config) :

  You didn't specify config translation yaml file. Default settings are used.

Error in multmerge(all_files, sep) :
 
  Key translation is not the same in all files.
```

Even when I comment all the app, just running the first line for defining the translation gives me this error.

I have created a csv file for translation.

The code is:

```
 library(shiny)

 library(shiny.i18n)

 i18n <- Translator$new(translation_csvs_path = "translation_no.csv")

 i18n$set_translation_language("en")

 ui <- fluidPage(p(i18n$t("Hello")))

 server <- function(input, output) {}

 shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I have saved the csv file in the same directory as my working directory. The csv file is:

```
 en,no

 Hello,Hei
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have two issues with your code.

First, to address the error, the `translation_csvs_path` parameter expects the path to the root of the directory that contains the CSV files to be used for translation. If you have the translations in the same directory as the rest of your R code, then the following should work:

```
i18n <- Translator$new(translation_csvs_path = ".")
```

Although it is recommended that you move all of the translations to a directory instead, this will help organize the application if/when it increases in size and complexity.

Second the warning,

```
Warning in load_local_config(translation_csv_config) :
  You didn't specify config translation yaml file. Default settings are used.
```

This one is a bit vague, but shiny.i18n is warning you that a YAML configuration file has not been supplied that [contains cultural localization information](https://appsilon.com/internationalization-of-shiny-apps-i18n/), so the default values will be used. An [example of such a file can be found on GitHub](https://github.com/Appsilon/shiny.i18n/blob/main/inst/config.yaml) and looks like this:

```
cultural_date_format: "%d/%m/%Y"
cultural_bignumer_mark: " "
cultural_punctuation_mark: ","
```

Although it's unclear what settings are possible. However, the file can be supplied during initialization by setting the `translation_csv_config` parameter:

```
i18n <- Translator$new(translation_csvs_path = ".", translation_csv_config = "config.yml")
```

Comment: I faced this same problem today.  The error message " Key translation is not the same in all files." is related to the csvs_path cofig.  
I use shiny.i18n inside of shiny. the path is relative to shiny modules. So, some time , it will report the issue.